# The reason for the automatic correction shortcut key (ctrl + K + D) not working for some code (in Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, shortcut

[image]

[image]

As it is clear in the two screenshots, some parts of the code are messed up after pressing the shortcut key, and after pressing the shortcut key, some parts are fixed (the parts related to calculations and value assignment are bugged). Is there a solution to this problem? (Visual Studio 2022)

[image]

After pressing the <kbd>Ctrl+K+D</kbd> keys, it will arrange all the codes in this way, but this does not happen

Comment: Looks like formatting was applied up to the first syntax error?

Comment: No, I tried without error, but only the sections related to calculations and assignments are not arranged @GSerg

Comment: It works in Visual Studio 2022 v17.5.0. I never knew that this existed and therefore have never used it. Not sure how I've gotten by all these years.

Comment: In my opinion it works for some basic errors, you can use Alt+enter with it. This shortcut key belongs to the text editor. Your 5+5=10 is not recognized here as part of the c# code, its error is more primitive. So this shortcut key won't fix it.